# Errors when creating function

Tags: sql-server, function, if-statement, sql-server-2016

This sort of follows on from my previous question but I have gone about it a different way as I have found out that what I was trying to do, I cannot do in a view, it needs to be a function.

However I have got the code attached to the bottom of this thread but I am getting these errors:

```
Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Procedure fn_COT_TEST, Line 27 [Batch Start Line 0]
The multi-part identifier "Contact_Group_Contacts_T.Relationship_Code_ID" could not be bound.
Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Procedure fn_COT_TEST, Line 27 [Batch Start Line 0]
The multi-part identifier "Contact_Group_Contacts_T.Relationship_Code_ID" could not be bound.
Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Procedure fn_COT_TEST, Line 27 [Batch Start Line 0]
The multi-part identifier "Contact_Group_Contacts_T.Relationship_Code_ID" could not be bound.
Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Procedure fn_COT_TEST, Line 27 [Batch Start Line 0]
The multi-part identifier "Contact_Group_Contacts_T.Relationship_Code_ID" could not be bound.
Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Procedure fn_COT_TEST, Line 27 [Batch Start Line 0]
The multi-part identifier "Contact_Group_Contacts_T.Relationship_Code_ID" could not be bound.
Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Procedure fn_COT_TEST, Line 27 [Batch Start Line 0]
The multi-part identifier "Contact_Group_Contacts_T.Relationship_Code_ID" could not be bound.
Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Procedure fn_COT_TEST, Line 27 [Batch Start Line 0]
The multi-part identifier "Contact_Group_Contacts_T.Relationship_Code_ID" could not be bound.
Msg 444, Level 16, State 2, Procedure fn_COT_TEST, Line 27 [Batch Start Line 0]
Select statements included within a function cannot return data to a client.
Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Procedure fn_COT_TEST, Line 29 [Batch Start Line 0]
The multi-part identifier "Contact_Group_Contacts_T.Main_Group_Contact_BT" could not be bound.
Msg 444, Level 16, State 2, Procedure fn_COT_TEST, Line 29 [Batch Start Line 0]
Select statements included within a function cannot return data to a client.
Msg 455, Level 16, State 2, Procedure fn_COT_TEST, Line 29 [Batch Start Line 0]
The last statement included within a function must be a return statement.
```

My code is below. I have tried my hardest but am completely stuck. What am I doing wrong?

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[fn_COT_POA] (@CONTACT_ID INT)
RETURNS VARCHAR
AS
BEGIN 

DECLARE @COUNT INT;
SET @COUNT =
(select COUNT(CONTACT_ID)
 from Contact_Group_Contacts_T
 where CONTACT_ID = @CONTACT_ID)
RETURN @COUNT

IF @COUNT > 1
    select @CONTACT_ID where Contact_Group_Contacts_T.Relationship_Code_ID in (2801,2802,2803,2804,2805,2806,2807)
    ELSE
    select @CONTACT_ID where Contact_Group_Contacts_T.Main_Group_Contact_BT = 1

END
GO
```

What I am trying to do is only select contacts that have those relationship code ID's, if they haven't got those relationship code ID's then select the contact that has the main_group_contact_bt flag as 1.

Thanks Dan

Comment: Tag the dbms you're using. That code is product specific.

Comment: Why do you have this line in the middle of your function? `return @count` Your function wants to stops after it returns something.

Comment: @SqlZim - I was following a sample online that might give me hints. I didnt know if I should or not. Doesn't work if I take it out anyway

Comment: @jarlh - SQL Server 2016

Comment: @SqlZim - so does the RETURN COUNT need to be at the end of the function code?

Comment: Change this select @COUNT= COUNT(CONTACT_ID) from Contact_Group_Contacts_T where CONTACT_ID = @CONTACT_ID

Comment: I'm still trying to figure out what you are trying to do. Are you trying to get a result set? or are you trying to use this in a query to get a name? or are you trying to use this to get a number of contacts someone has?

Comment: This sounds like an [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/346416). I know everyone always asks what have you tried so far, but we also need to know the problem you are trying to solve.

Comment: @dgoodwin It sounds like you need a table valued function then, inline table valued function if possible. [TSQL User-Defined Functions: Ten Questions You Were Too Shy To Ask - Robert Sheldon](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/sql-training/tsql-user-defined-functions-ten-questions-you-were-too-shy-to-ask/)

Comment: Sorry if I havent explained myself properly. I am trying to pull contact_id's from the contact_group_contacts_t table, these link to contact names in a different table... now, I only want to select contact_id with a certain relationship code. If contacts have other relationship codes against their record, then I want to show the contact_id with main_group_contact_bt set as 1. Hope this makes sense?

Comment: Does anyone know what I can do to return the results I need? Thanks for your help in advance.

Answer (score 0):

This is just a shot in the dark after looking at your previous question, but maybe you are looking for something like this:

```
create function dbo.udf_cot_poa (@group_id int) 
returns table 
as return 
select top 1 /* getting just the first one*/
    Contact.*
from Contact_Group_Contacts_T as Grp
  inner join contact_contacts_t as Contact
    on grp.contact_id = contact.contact_id
   and contact.current_status_id = 65
   and contact.deceased_date_dt is null 
where grp.group_id = @contact_id
  and grp.Removed_BT = 0
order by case
  when grp.Relationship_Code_ID in (2801,2802,2803,2804,2805,2806,2807) /* related first */ 
    then 0
  when grp.Main_Group_Contact_BT = 1 /* this one second */
    then 1
  else 2 /* if neither of those exist then whatever does */
  end
go

select * from dbo.udf_cot_poa(group_id);
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for this, I have tried to do this however it came up with errors, also I changed a couple of the parameters - on line 1, i changed (at)group_id to (at)contact_id as I would like to report on the contact_id, not the group_id. Also on line 11, I changed to grp.contact_id = (at)contact_id ... this creates the function correctly but I am getting this error: Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Invalid column name 'contact_id'.

Comment: @dgoodwin update your question with your table definitions and foreign keys